# DatePicker with Date Only

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

I want to get a date data from a form but only the date, not including the month nor the year. Can I use datepicker in the form but with the date only? If it's not possible, what the efficient way to get date information from a form ? Thanks

Comment: So you just want a number?

Comment: number 1 to 31(date) yes

Comment: why don't you use a simple spinner?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [`NumberPicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html), but it's only
   available starting from API level 11.

Alternatively:

- You can use an `EditText`, with `inputType="number"`, and do you
  checking of being in the 1..31 range in code.
- You can use a `SeekBar`, and display the value next to it
  dynamically.
- You can use a `Spinner`, and list the 31 possibilities.